# How I include a module (this module has a module inside that) inside another module in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a module as following,

main.rb:

```
module Main
 include Dad::Mam
end
```

and

in dad.rb:

```
module Dad
 module Mam
  puts "Mam is saying you are very lazy..."
 end
end
```

How can I name this file? dad.rb is right?

but when running

`$ ruby main.rb`

I am getting an Error like,

> main.rb:2:in `<module:Main>': uninitialized constant Main::Dad
>   (NameError)   from main.rb:1:in`'

I need to show the sentance inside the puts under `Mam` module while running ruby `main.rb`,

I am confused about using ruby's modules, please anyone help me and guide me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, since you're just writing a simple script, use `#require_relative`

```
require_relative 'dad'
module Main
 include Dad::Mam
end
```

For an actual app or library, you would want to manage the load path (a global variable holding an array that tells ruby where to look for files) and then use a normal `require`